# Compare multiple arrays for all keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, comparison

I have a little trouble with PHP arrays and some comparison I'd like to do. Sorry for my bad english :(

I'm building a picture management system. The user can select multiple pictures at a time, and edit the information for all the selected pictures. But some fields are already filled in - and I'd like to show the user a '*' char if a specific field is filled with different information for multiple pictures.

My problem is the following :
- I have a two-dimension array containing mySQL query results for all the pictures selected (this number of course is indefinite). 
Here's an example of the resulting array :

```
Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [Folder_id] => 40
        [Title_fr] => test
        [Title_en] => 
        [Desc_fr] => 
        [Desc_en] => 
        [Place_fr] => Koksijde, Belgique
        [Place_en] => Koksijde, Belgium
        [Place_ICAO] => EBBE
        [Place_city] => 
        [Place_country] => be
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Folder_id] => 40
        [Title_fr] => test
        [Title_en] => 
        [Desc_fr] => 
        [Desc_en] => 
        [Place_fr] => Koksijde, Belgique
        [Place_en] => Koksijde, Belgium
        [Place_ICAO] => EBBE
        [Place_city] => 
        [Place_country] => be
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Folder_id] => 40
        [Title_fr] => test
        [Title_en] => 
        [Desc_fr] => 
        [Desc_en] => 
        [Place_fr] => Koksijde, Belgique
        [Place_en] => Koksijde, Belgium
        [Place_ICAO] => EBBE
        [Place_city] => 
        [Place_country] => be
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Folder_id] => 51
        [Title_fr] => test
        [Title_en] => 
        [Desc_fr] => 
        [Desc_en] => 
        [Place_fr] => FRANC
        [Place_en] => ANGLE
        [Place_ICAO] => ENGL
        [Place_city] => Münich2
        [Place_country] => de
    )
```

As you can see, some fields may be common for all the records, some may be different. For instance, [Place_fr] is not the same for all the records, but [Desc_fr] is.

I'd like to code a function that returns an array with all the fields as key, and with '*' as value if this field contains different values between records, and the value if it is common for all records.

For instance, the result here would be :

```
 Array
 ( 
        [Folder_id] => *
        [Title_fr] => test
        [Title_en] => 
        [Desc_fr] => 
        [Desc_en] => 
        [Place_fr] => *
        [Place_en] => *
        [Place_ICAO] => *
        [Place_city] => *
        [Place_country] => *
 )
```

I know this could be done using array_diff_assoc(). It's quite easy to be done with two arrays. The problem is that I would have to pass an undefinite number of arguments to this function and I don't know how this could be solved.

Sorry for the noob question - I'm just a beginer when it comes to arrays.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
// get common keys => values
$common  = call_user_func_array('array_intersect_assoc', $arr);

// and append missing keys to them, with "*" values
$common += array_fill_keys(array_keys($arr[0]), '*');
```

(assuming that `$arr` is your array above)

Comment: I actually think your answer is better. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrays = array (
    array (
        "Folder_id" => 40,
        "Title_fr" => "test",
        "Title_en" => "",
        "Desc_fr" => "",
        "Desc_en" => "",
        "Place_fr" => "Koksijde, Belgique",
        "Place_en" => "Koksijde, Belgium",
        "Place_ICAO" => "EBBE",
        "Place_city" => "",
        "Place_country" => "be"
    ),
    array (
        "Folder_id" => 40,
        "Title_fr" => "test",
        "Title_en" => "",
        "Desc_fr" => "",
        "Desc_en" => "",
        "Place_fr" => "Koksijde, Belgique",
        "Place_en" => "Koksijde, Belgium",
        "Place_ICAO" => "EBBE",
        "Place_city" => "",
        "Place_country" => "be"
    ),
    array (
        "Folder_id" => 40,
        "Title_fr" => "test",
        "Title_en" => "",
        "Desc_fr" => "",
        "Desc_en" => "",
        "Place_fr" => "Koksijde, Belgique",
        "Place_en" => "Koksijde, Belgium",
        "Place_ICAO" => "EBBE",
        "Place_city" => "",
        "Place_country" => "be"
    ),
    array (
        "Folder_id" => 51,
        "Title_fr" => "test",
        "Title_en" => "",
        "Desc_fr" => "",
        "Desc_en" => "",
        "Place_fr" => "FRANC",
        "Place_en" => "ANGLE",
        "Place_ICAO" => "ENGL",
        "Place_city" => "Münich2",
        "Place_country" => "de"
    )
);

function compare($arrays) {
    foreach ($arrays as $array) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (!isset($result[$key])) {
                $result[$key] = $value;
            } else if ($result[$key] !== "*") {
                if ($value !== $result[$key]) {
                    $result[$key] = "*";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(compare($arrays));
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: That is spot-on what I wanted to achieve !
Thanks very much for your help, it's really appreciated !

Comment: @ClémentChristomanos You should consider One Trick Pony's answer as well.